# KRL convert string to lowercase in pre block

Tags: string, lowercase, krl

### Question

Is there a way in the pre block of a rule to convert a string to all lower case?

### Background

I have a regular expression that returns parts of a string and sometimes they start with an uppercase and sometimes not. Because I want to use the result from the regex as a key in a hashmap I need the case to always be consistent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yup! `lc()` is your friend. Rule example:

```
rule example {
 select when somedomain someevent
  pre {
    x = "FOO";
    y = x.lc();
  }
  noop();
}
```

Docs Link: http://docs.kynetx.com/docs/Lc